# Android Room: multi-module project in kotlin

Tags: android, android-room, kapt

Had anyone a success with using Room with multi-module Android?

Whenever I have all my Entities classes in my main module everything compiles properly.
When I move any entity class (e.g. `Person.kt`) to domain module that the main module is based on, the compilation of the entire project fails.
It seems not to find the file that was generated (`Person.java`) that is located now in the domain module.

I use the `kotlin-kapt` plugin in both modules and it generates the proper file, but for some reason, it is not picked up by the main module.

Comment: Some notes here: https://jacquessmuts.github.io/post/modularization_room/ and here: https://medium.com/mindorks/writing-a-modular-project-on-android-304f3b09cb37